# How can i create two register forms for different users?

Tags: 7, users

How can i have two register forms and show register form for two sets of users.

One register form for one set of users and another register form for another set of users?

one can be default drupal form that is user/register. But i want url to be varied.

Answer (score 4):

Use the [Profile2 Registration Path](https://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) module. It can help you in creating as many registering forms as you need. I have used this one.

> This module enables administrators to set unique registration paths per Profile2 profile type.
>
> ### Overview
>
> #### The Problem
>
> By default, the Profile 2 module permits you to add fields from chosen profile types to the default user registration form. Unfortunately, there is only one user registration form. Thus, every user will be presented with these fields during registration. If you have two profile types targeted at two different audiences, you cannot have two separate registration forms.

[Profile 2](https://drupal.org/project/profile2) use this module to get different set of fields. While editing the profile you have created, you can check this one.

- Unique registration path
  Enable unique registration path
- Settings
  URL path http://ram.site.dev/customer/register

Answer (score 3):

Check out the [Profile2 Registration Path](https://drupal.org/project/profile2_regpath) and the [Profile 2](https://drupal.org/project/profile2) modules.

**Profile2 Registration Path**

> This module enables administrators to set unique registration paths per Profile2 profile type.

**Profile 2**

> - The module is aimed to provide a simple, but extensible solution    providing a similar end user interface like the core profile module
>     by default.
> - Multiple profile types may be created via the UI (e.g. a general    profile + a customer profile), whereas the module provides separated
>     permissions for those.
> - Optionally, profile forms are shown during user account registration.

Here is a [quick tutorial](http://www.grasmash.com/article/managing-account-registration-multiple-user-types) you can also follow to set it up.

> - Download Profile2 and profile registration path
> - Enable the modules
> - Create the 'consumer' and 'service provider' roles
> - Go to admin/structure/profiles and add a new profile type named    'consumer'
> - Check 'Enable unique registration path'
> - Enter a URL path to use for this profile type, e.g.,    'consumer/register'
> - Select the role(s) that you would like to apply to users registering    from this path. In this case, 'consumer'
> - Add a few fields to the profile type
> - Create additional profile types as needed
> - Configure your permissions so that the correct roles can edit the    correct profile types. E.g., only users with role 'consumer' can edit 
>     profiles of type 'consumer'